# Is Spray allowing only one thread within the routing code?

Tags: multithreading, akka, spray

[Spray routing](http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-SNAPSHOT/spray-routing/) is based on the Akka actor system. In all the sample code I remember, routing is done "fast" and actual work is spawned to other actors, unless it needs to be done synchronically to gain a response.

I would need to validate a POST input that may take some time (100's of milliseconds). Is the HTTP server going to be busy during this time, with regard to other incoming requests (s.a. normal GETs)?

In other words, what's the Spray routing multithreading model, really?

I can spawn the validation to another actor, but in such a case the REST API response will no longer be able to report if there is an error with the incoming contents. What's the optimum way to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

1) The `listener` parameter of `Http.Bind.apply()` can be an actor pool. In this case you will have several identical actors to run your route with several HTTP requests simultaneously.

2) Usually you should not do any blocking calls and/or heavy tasks inside an actor, including a Spray routing actor. In general will be better to use another pool of actors for doing such tasks, using ask pattern from your spray route, or create a temporary per-request actor (don't forget to set `setReceiveTimeout` and handle timeouts in it) whom can send a message to another actor and wait for the answer (and die after answering to the HTTP request) or create a simple `Future`, include the Spray's request context (ctx) to this Actor or Future and allow them to do such a work in their separate threads, completing the request context with proper HTTP status and entity when all work will be done (but you should avoid passing the Spray request context to any actors as a message or a message part, because it has heavy context including not serializable parts in it).